# Ошибка CS0234 при попытке обратится к коду из папки Editor

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Метод который надо вызвать в классе PlacementObjects

```
namespace TerrainStitch
{

    public class TerrainStitchEditor : EditorWindow
    {
       ...
        public static void TerrainStitcherOnGUI()
        {
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

Класс в котором вызываю TerrainStitcherOnGUI()

```
namespace marijnz.EditorCoroutines
{     public class PlacementObjects : EditorWindow
    {
               void OnGUI()
        {
         TerrainStitch.TerrainStitchEditor.TerrainStitcherOnGUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'TerrainStitchEditor' does not exist in the namespace 'TerrainStitch' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Иерархия папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну я вот с чего: рантайм код **ни в коем случае** не должен ссылаться на Editor код.

Во-первых, это чисто с точки зрения не совсем понятная логика, Editor код предназначен для редактора, а не для игровой логики. [Во-вторых, любые Editor скрипты никогда не попадают в билды.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html)

> Scripts placed in a folder called Editor are treated as Editor scripts
>   rather than runtime scripts. These scripts add functionality to the
>   Editor during development, and are not available in builds at runtime.
>
> You can have multiple Editor folders placed anywhere inside the Assets
>   folder. Place your Editor scripts inside an Editor folder or a
>   subfolder within it.

---

В данном конкретном случае все скрипты в папках с названием "Editor" и их подпапках будут скомпилированы в отдельную dll'ку, когда все остальные .cs файлы будут скомпилированы в другую dll'ку, между ними никаких связей нет, поэтому и возникла ошибка из вопроса. Решаемо ли это? Чисто теоретически можно указать взаимосвязь между этими библиотеками, но в рантайме этот код все равно не будет работать.

Comment: Убрал из папки  Editor скомпилировалось нормально

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что в свойствах файла, в котором описан класс TerrainStitchEditor, в пункте "Действие при сборке" стоит "Компилировать"

Comment: Можно поподробней описать?

Comment: Не в этом проблема.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker А в чём может быть ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov позже оформлю ответ

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Да спасибо буду очень благодарен